# NServiceBus & WindsorCastle : method configure does not have an implementation

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, console-application, nservicebus

Using those packages :

```
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="3.0.0.4001" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor" version="3.0.0.4001" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="log4net" version="1.2.10" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NServiceBus" version="3.3.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NServiceBus.CastleWindsor-CI" version="3.0.2223" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NServiceBus.Interfaces" version="3.3.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="RavenDB.Client" version="2.0.2261" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I got an exception stating that "***the Configure method of ServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.CastleWindsor does not have an implementation***"

I checked that with DotPeek and it has one.  I guess NServiceBus is looking for another signature.

Interesting enough, removing the call to *CastleWindsorBuilder()* while configuring the Bus does not change anything.  It seems NServiceBus is doing reflection on all assembly that are present in the application folder and look for a ConfigureMethod.  How can I circumvent this process to look into the NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.CastleWindsor component ?

Off course, removing that assembly from my Bin folder does helps but keep me far away from integrating WindsroCastle and NServiceBus which I need :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to

```
  <package id="NServiceBus" version="3.3.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NServiceBus.CastleWindsor" version="3.2.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NServiceBus.CastleWindsor-CI" version="3.2.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NServiceBus.Interfaces" version="3.3.5" targetFramework="net45" />
```

solved the problem

Comment: Just heads up that we have [obsolete the -CI packages](https://nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.CastleWindsor-CI/), so you shouldn't reference _NServiceBus.CastleWindsor-CI_ package